# Can i use string type with having clause(Like ....having sex='male')

Tags: mysql, database, oracle11g, group-by, having-clause

select country,count(*) from employee group by country having id<4;
this query works fine but when i use
select country,count(*) from employee group by country having sex='male';
showing error :-ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the firts should work  because there is the same aggregation level between country and id  (each country have one id only)

the second  don't work  because sex is not an aggregated  column   and have not the same aggregation level  so

you should use where for filter  if you don't need  sex in aggregation clause

```
  select country,count(*) from employee 
  where  sex='male'
  group by country;
```

or you could add sex to the group by and filter

```
  select country,sex,  count(*) from employee 
  group by country, sex
  having sez='male';
```